# Bleed variable amount outside of grid on one side only

Tags: susy-compass, susy-sass, susy

I am using susy2 for a project and I would like to include an image that bleeds outside of grid only on the left side and then spans 7 columns within the grid.  The problem is, I do not think I can just use bleed because the amount to bleed is not constant.

This diagram should better explain what I'm going for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFd6H.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: The only solution I've seen for this involves massive bleed — so it overflows the edge at most sizes. But that solution doesn't help if you need an image to start at the edge.